# How to render {{ }} during ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dom, angularjs-directive

consider following directive:

```
.directive('otherDirective', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      console.log(elem[0]);
      alert(elem[0]);
    }

  }
```

if I apply it into a ng-repeat tag, I can notice the {{item}} is not evaluated until the ng-repeat ends (when blocked by `alert()`). how can I have it rendered after each "loop"?

Because in real scenario, those items contain an image, and I would like to do callbacks after each image is loaded, but without the img url I can't bind the event.

[here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zm11sIruXfOSZpLo9yP7?p=preview)

Comment: You need to wait till `ng-repeat` completes its rendering..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are assigning the img src via the `ng-repeat` scope variable `{{x}}`. In that case you could simply put `onload` event if you are really interested till image element is loaded. I'd suggest you to use the `on('load', funnction(){ //code })` event. This event will call function whenever image gets loaded to the DOM.

**Code**

```
.directive('otherDirective', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        //element before loading
        console.log(elem[0]);
        elem.find('img').on('load', function() {
          //element after loaded
          console.log(elem[0]);
          //if you are going to manipulate scope binding here
          //then you have to run digest cycle manually
          //as this event will considered as outside of angular context
          //after binding/DOM manipulation is done..do apply digest by doing scope.$apply()
        })
      }
    }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yHwquZ82OQMQyD2VAtnz?p=preview)

Comment: nice `$timeout`-less solution

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yepp..As OP is more interested in callback on image load..then mine answer cover what he wants... :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `$timeout` to wait for `ng-repeat` to finish: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZjsaCJxwfhC3J91k3RL?p=preview)

```
.directive('otherDirective',['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      $timeout(function () {
        console.log(elem[0]);
        alert(elem[0]);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I think this would be an appropriate..safe run digest cycle +1